# azure appservice container not getting HTTPS schem

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-appservice

I have a simple asp.net core 3.1 app that prints out the HTTPRequest in the index.cshtml page.
I containerized the app and am running it in azure appservice.

There is a lot of code I don't own, microsoft OIDC stuff for example, that relies on HTTPRequest.Scheme to build out redirect URLs.  The request going into my containerized app is HTTP, even though the original request url looks like this;

```
https://app-chaosbunny.azurewebsites.net/
```

when I print out what the app thinks is in the HTTPRequest, I get;

```
http://app-chaosbunny.azurewebsites.net/
```

Needless to say when the OIDC stuff builds the redirectUrl it is the HTTP scheme, which is wrong.

There is a TLS/SSL settings for "App Services" where you can turn "HTTPS Only" on.  This has no effect.

Am I missing a setting that enforces the right scheme gets passed along to the container?

Comment: App Service should not impact the upcoming URL in any way. Are you sure you don't have any rewrite logic in your container? What are you using as a web server? Could you show you initialization logic / Dockerfile?

Comment: [dockerfile](https://github.com/fluffy-bunny/chaos-bunny/blob/master/src/InMemoryIdentityApp/Dockerfile)  
btw: the https://app-chaosbunny.azurewebsites.net/ is live so you can see it in action.

Comment: Could you also post how you get the request URL?

Comment: [razor prints HTTPRequest](https://github.com/fluffy-bunny/chaos-bunny/blob/master/src/InMemoryIdentityApp/Pages/Index.cshtml)  btw: I first noticed this when the OIDC builds out the redirectUrl=http://blah.  You can see this when you go to "login" and google.  the OIDC libraries use Request.Scheme, which is http.  The app runs fine locally from VS, and via [docker compose](https://github.com/fluffy-bunny/chaos-bunny/blob/master/src/docker-compose.yml).  So it surprised me to see it fail on app service.

Comment: I reproduced this using the out-of-the-box VS webapp [docker template](https://github.com/fluffy-bunny/chaos-bunny/blob/master/src/SimpleApp/Dockerfile).   The only change I made to the app was adding to the index.cshtml displaying of the HTTPRequest.  So it has to be that AppService, which was following the Azure tutorials.  Next is creating a new AppService to see if I did something wrong there.

Comment: I reproduced it by creating a brand new WebApp for containers, basically clicking next->next and only giving the details of where my docker image is.  [new app](https://simpleapp-container.azurewebsites.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this is happening because of the fact that App Service terminates SSL at the front-end. The request that makes it to the worker your app is on is always going to be HTTP. Check for the X-Arr-Ssl header. The presence of that header tells you the request came in as an SSL request.

Jim

Comment: Ok so I did a little experiment which left me more confused even though it works.  I added a middleware right after UseHttpsRedirection to force the scheme to be https.  Why isn't the UseHttpsRedirection producing an infinite loop?    

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (!context.Request.IsHttps)
                {
                    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                }
                // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
                await next();
            });

Comment: [site](https://simpleapp-container.azurewebsites.net/)  The https scheme is me forcing it in a mddleware.  There is a X-ARR-SSL=2048|256|C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 5|CN=*.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0):

[proxy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Without specific documentation on what is happening with app service for containers in azure this answer may not be correct, but it  works.

I found that the following headers where being sent from appService into the containerized app.

```
X-ARR-SSL   2048|256|C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 5|CN=*.azurewebsites.net
X-Forwarded-Proto   https
X-AppService-Proto  https
```

The following approach listed in the docs did not work for me.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

***start snippet***

**When it isn't possible to add forwarded headers and all requests are secure**

In some cases, it might not be possible to add forwarded headers to the requests proxied to the app. If the proxy is enforcing that all public external requests are HTTPS, the scheme can be manually set in `Startup.Configure` before using any type of middleware:

C#
Copy

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```

This code can be disabled with an environment variable or other configuration setting in a development or staging environment.
***end snippet***

I put the following code at the first line of my `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
      context.Request.Scheme = "https";
      await next();
    });

    ....
}
```